# Использование переменных строкового типа в XPath

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt

В файле XSLT есть переменная, формируемая динамически, строкового типа. Как использовать это строку в XPath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ сам нашел: версии 1.0 и 2.0(которые стандартизованы) не поддерживают динамическую генерацию XPath. В будущей версие 2.1 планируется эта фишка.
Поэтому сейчас есть два варианта:

1. Расширение dyn, которое поддерживается далеко не всеим парсерами
2. Два преобразования xslt: первое получает на выходе файл xslt с прописанным XPath.